# Compact access to variables in nested structures

Tags: c, struct, nested

Given this simple C code:

```
struct { 
    struct a {
        int foo;
    };
    struct b {
        char *bar;
    };
} s;
```

I am wondering whether there is a way to access a variable in one of the nested structures in a more compact way than `s.a.foo = 5`, for instance.

Comment: Not really. By the way, `s.a.foo` does not work as written, because `a` is the struct tag, not the name of the element...

Comment: The only exception would be if he set up a pointer to `s.a` and then used the pointer to access `foo`.... `struct a *ptr = s.a; ptr->foo...;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that your example is not standard C89 (but it is acceptable by some compilers when you ask for some language extensions. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) you'll need to extend the accepted [C dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) with the  `-fms-extensions` flag to the compiler). You are using [unnamed fields](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html). A more standard way of coding would be:

```
struct a {
   int foo;
};
struct b {
   char* bar;
};
struct {
    struct a aa;
    struct b bb;
} s;
```

Back to your question, no, there is no other way. However, you might use preprocessor macros, whcih could help. For instance, assuming the above declarations, you could

```
#define afoo aa.foo
#define bbar bb.bar
```

and then you can code `s.afoo` instead of `s.aa.foo`

You might also define macros like

```
#define AFOO(X) (X).aa.foo
```

and then code `AFOO(s)`

Using such preprocessor macros does have some annoyance:  with my example, you cannot declare anymore a variable (or formal argument, or field, or function) named `afoo`

But I am not sure you should bother. My personal advice & habit is to give longer and often unique names to fields (and also to name `struct a_st` my `struct`-ures). Take advantage of the auto-completion abilities of your editor. Don't forget that your code is more often read than written, so use meaningful names in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not. You have to specify the path the the memory address you wish to reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast structs directly, but you can cast pointers to structs. So if you have this stuct:

```
typedef struct { 
    struct {
        int foo;
    } a;
    struct {
            char bar;
        } b;
} s;
```

You can create a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
    char bar;
} sa;
```

Now when you create the struct, stash a pointer to it:

```
s myS;
myS.a.foo = 123;
myS.b.bar = 10;

sa *mySA = (sa *)&myS;
```

Then you can do this:

```
printf("I'm really a s.a.bar %d", (*mySA).bar);
```

Which will print out the appropriate value.

So now you can do:

```
(*mySA).bar = 22;
printf("%d", myS.b.bar);
```

You aren't really saving that much typing though.